# .Net 4.5 Winforms Process Anything Past X Days old

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, .net-4.5

So, I've got this great little app, that will recursively search a directory for a given file extension... zip the files it finds, then delete the original... except the latest file

What I'm wondering is how can I incorporate a way to process the files that are X number of days old?

For instance, say I have a log directory, and in it there are 365 *.log files.  Right now, my code will zip and delete all but the latest one...  I'd like to add an option in to do any that are older than X number of days old... say anything older than 30 days old.

Here's my existing code that does the work now:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.Compression

Public Class DoTheWork

Public _ct As Long = 0

Public Function Work(ByVal _PathToSearch As String, ByVal _Ext As String, ByVal _Worker As BackgroundWorker) As Boolean
    Try
        Dim _DI As New DirectoryInfo(_PathToSearch)
        Dim _Files = _DI.EnumerateFiles("*." & _Ext, SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList
        Dim _fCt As Long = _Files.Count
        For i = 0 To _fCt - 1
            Dim _Path As String = _Files(i).DirectoryName
            Dim _FullName As String = _Files(i).FullName
            If Not GetNewestFile(_Path).FullName.Equals(_FullName) Then
                Dim _FileName As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(_Files(i).Name)
                Using _z As ZipArchive = ZipFile.Open(_Path & "\" & _FileName & ".zip", ZipArchiveMode.Create)
                    _z.CreateEntryFromFile(_FullName, _Files(i).Name, CompressionLevel.Optimal)
                End Using
                File.Delete(_FullName)
            End If
            ReportProgress(_Perc(i, _fCt), _Worker)
        Next
        ReportProgress(100, _Worker)
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function

Private Sub ReportProgress(ByVal ct As Integer, _Worker As BackgroundWorker)
    If _Worker IsNot Nothing Then
        _Worker.ReportProgress(ct)
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(250)
    End If
End Sub

Private Function _Perc(num, ct) As Integer
    If num = 0 Then
        Return 1
    Else
        Return (num / ct) * 100
    End If
End Function

Private Function GetNewestFile(_path As String) As FileInfo
    Dim di As New DirectoryInfo(_path)
    Return (di.GetFiles("*.bak").OrderByDescending(Function(f) f.LastWriteTime).First())
End Function

End Class
```

**UPDATE:**

```
Public Function Work(ByVal _PathToSearch As String,
                     ByVal _Ext As String,
                     Optional ByVal _DaysToKeep As Double = 1,
                     Optional ByVal _Worker As BackgroundWorker = Nothing) As Boolean
    Try
        Dim _DI As New DirectoryInfo(_PathToSearch)
        Dim _Files As List(Of FileInfo) = _DI.EnumerateFiles("*." & _Ext, SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList
        Dim _now As Date = Now()
        Dim _ToKeep = _now.AddDays(CDbl(-_DaysToKeep))
        Dim _fCt As Integer = _Files.Count
        Dim i As Long = 0
        For Each _file As FileInfo In _Files.Where(Function(fi) fi.CreationTimeUtc.CompareTo(_ToKeep))
            Dim _Path As String = _file.DirectoryName
            Dim _FullName As String = _file.FullName
            Dim _FileName As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(_file.Name)
            Using _z As ZipArchive = ZipFile.Open(_Path & "\" & _FileName & ".zip", ZipArchiveMode.Create)
                _z.CreateEntryFromFile(_FullName, _file.Name, CompressionLevel.Optimal)
            End Using
            'File.Delete(_FullName)
            ReportProgress(_Perc(i, _fCt), _Worker)
            i += 1
        Next
        ReportProgress(100, _Worker)
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

The `.Where` statement completely ignores `_ToKeep`

Comment: It is a one liner with Linq, use the Select() and Where() extension methods.

Comment: It's just one line (and a small a aubergine).... well if it is what is it?

Comment: just for reference: (you're creating all the log files yourself so should be fine but) file creation and modified times are unreliable. when copying files, the time changes, when moving them, it doesn't. and even then, there are some specific cases which break those rules. unless you created those files, and never copied them from their original location, then you're guessing at best.

Comment: these files will be system generated and really rarely ever touched unless they need to be restored

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but when you do `ReportProgress(_Perc(i, _fCt), _Worker)` it would be a little bit better to only ReportProgress if the value has changed.

Comment: The .Where clause would prefer a Boolean, but you are giving it an Integer from [.CompareTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I suspect that if you put a `< 0` in there it would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like some code I wrote once for a .Net C# cache:

```
        public void CullCache()
        {
            var now = new DateTime().Date;
            now = now.AddDays(- (Math.Max(0, KeepDays - 1)) );

            var rootDir = new DirectoryInfo(LocationPathRoot);
            RecurseDirs(now, rootDir);
        }

        // Delete logs even if in sub directories.

        private void RecurseDirs(DateTime now, DirectoryInfo root)
        {
            FileInfo[] files = null;

            try
            {
                // get all the files directly under this folder 
                files = root.GetFiles("*.*"); 
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
            { 
                // Thrown if the files require permissions greater than the application provides.
                // just ignore for now       
            } 

            catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException)
            { 
                // just ignore for now
            }

            if (files != null)
            {
                // delete files created more than "KeepDays" ago...
                foreach (FileInfo fi in files.Where(fi => fi.CreationTimeUtc.CompareTo(now) < 0).Where(fi => FindCacheFile(fi.FullName)))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Delete {0}", fi.FullName);
                }

                foreach (var dirInfo in root.GetDirectories())
                {
                    RecurseDirs(now, dirInfo);
                }
            }
        }
```

you might want to change the GetFiles("*.*") to match the files you want to delete.

Comment: Just to clarify, I could change `GetNewestFile(_path As String)` to `GetNewestFile(_path As String, Byval _DaysToKeep as Integer)` and change that query in there to do the `.Where`?

Comment: So, i've changed the code to accomplish this, but it completely ignores the `_ToKeep`.  I've updated the question with the new `Work` function